# Android creating a file in /data/local/ and writng into it

Tags: java, android

I am using a non-activity class and I want to create a file in /data/local/ path. I am using Emulator for this. Once the file is created in this path, I want to write some String in the file for every 10 seconds.

Since I am using non-Activity class, I have no context working for me and I want to do without using context.

Could any one please help me how i could achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

My code is -

```
try {
                File myFile = new File("/data/local/tmp/welcome-to-java.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(tempList.toString());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Context` instance to access the file system :-) However, it is virtually impossible that you have "no context working for you", as every `Object` in Android runtime will actually be created in some `Context` (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver etc.), so just pass that Context into the Object :-)

And as for how to do it **with** `Context`, just use

```
yourContext.openFileOutput(path, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To obtain a `FileOutputStream` you need :-)

---

EDIT:

There is one way to avoid passing `Context` directly, but be warned that it is generally frowned upon. Namely, creating a custom `Application` class and making it a *Singleton*. This will allow you to access your `Context` from any place, but can also lead to severe memory leaks if, for example, you try using it in a long-running worker `Thread`. So use it wisely, if you really have to use it at all ;-)

Just to put it into perspective - first iterations of Android system actually provided static Context by default. I have also worked with a few current-time, commercial apps that use Application Singleton with no problems. So it is not that crazy of an idea. Nevertheless, it requires a huge dose of self-discipline to work out correctly.

Comment: No I mean it would work for me but I dont want to use it. I dont want to touch my Activity files and make them pass context to my non-activity files

Comment: And how exactly do you want to run your program without "touching your Activity files"? You need to create them and you need to create your file-saving Object in one of them, so you will touch them anyway.

Comment: No my point is I dont want to edit my Activity files for sending context. I need them for running my app. I am using AspectJ for getting data from activity files and sending it to my non-activity file which needs to write to internal storage. I want to use the Activity files as it is without editing them

Comment: I am not sure why you would like to attempt that, but it is not possible in Android to access the file system without Context instance. And what you just described seems a bit an anti-pattern :-( But see my Edit for one way

Comment: Yes i Know if i had "context" my life would have been a walk on cake :P But anyway thank you so much for your suggestion and time :)

Comment: See the edit for a working, but a bit dangerous solution ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> I am using a non-activity class and I want to create a file in /data/local/ path.

There is no `/data/local/` directory on production hardware that you can access sans root.

There *is* `/data/local/tmp/` that does seem to be world-readable and world-writeable. I would not recommend using it, as it is wide open for all parties, including attackers.

> Could any one please help me how i could achieve this?

Use Java file I/O, starting with `new File("/data/local/tmp/welcome-to-java.txt")`.

Comment: Ok i used this but when i check in my tmp folder, there is no file being created. I am using the code which I have put in my question(Edited)

Comment: @FAZ: I'd start by actually logging the exception. It's possible that `/data/local/tmp/` is only writeable by the `adb shell` account and not by apps. That would surprise me a bit, given that the `adb shell` account isn't as "special" on production hardware as it is on emulators.

Comment: When I print the exception it says java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) ; at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)

But I have added necessary permissions in Manifest file.

Comment: @FAZ: "But I have added necessary permissions in Manifest file" -- there are no permission elements of relevance here. This is not external storage. Apparently, `/data/local/tmp/` is read-write for the `adb shell` account but not for apps. In that case, writing anywhere in the `/data/local/` tree is unlikely to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help :) Even I did not know this fact. You helped me to learn :)